# Where is a SharePoint Community for Webparts?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, web-parts

I am searching a SharePoint Server 2007 Webpart which can do following

```
* change password
* lost password recovery (e-mail)
* change password reminder (e-mail)
```

I have been searching the Internet but somehow there aint as many webparts as for example WordPress Addons. When I am lucky I can find individuals which made an Webpart which matches one of the specs :(

The only things which come near my specs are

http://www.envisionit.com/Products/Pages/ExtranetModuleforSharePoint.aspx

http://userchangepassword.codeplex.com

I am wondering where I can find community's which have lots of Webparts to download or sell. Does anybody of you know such community's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I didn't find any great communities which are about web parts